# Efficient load CSV coordinate format (COO) input to local matrix spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, sparse-matrix, apache-spark-ml

I want to convert CSV coordinate format (COO) data into a local matrix. Currently I'm first converting them to `CoordinateMatrix` and then converting to `LocalMatrix`. But is there a better way to do this?

Example data:

```
0,5,5.486978435
0,3,0.438472867
0,0,6.128832321
0,7,5.295923198
0,1,7.738270234
```

Code:

```
var loadG = sqlContext.read.option("header", "false").csv("file.csv").rdd.map("mapfunctionCreatingMatrixEntryOutOfRow")
var G = new CoordinateMatrix(loadG)

var matrixG = G.toBlockMatrix().toLocalMatrix()
```

Comment: You'd be better with providing a [mcve] (including example data) and explaining motivation (sounds like a XY-problem and / or premature optimization if data is small enough for local matrix. It is also not clear why you use Spark at all, not to mention local linalg which, a bit useless) than a bounty.

Comment: Can you give some extra detail about what you want to achieve? It looks like you are using Spark only to parse a CSV file and then have a DenseMatrix on the driver. Is it like this or is there something which is missing that can help the community give a meaningful answer?

Comment: Yes I want to parse that CSV file, create a DenseMatrix out of the data and do lots of linear algebra with those Matrices.

Comment: I even have to do matrix multiplication/addition element-wise multiplication inside loops. (Reason I have to use spark = school project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`LocalMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-data-types.html#local-matrix) will be stored on a single machine and hence not make use of Spark's strengths. In other words, using Spark seems a bit wasteful, although still possible.

The easiest way to get the CSV file to a `LocalMatrix` is to first read the CSV with Scala, not Spark:

```
val entries = Source.fromFile("data.csv").getLines()
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(a => (a(0).toInt, a(1).toInt, a(2).toDouble))
  .toSeq
```

The [`SparseMatrix`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix) variant of the `LocalMatrix` has a method for reading COO formatted data. The number of rows and columns need to be specified to use this. Since the matrix is sparse this should in most cases be done by hand but it's possible to get the highest values in the data as follows:

```
val numRows = entries.map(_._1).max + 1
val numCols = entries.map(_._2).max + 1
```

Then create the matrix:

```
val matrixG = SparseMatrix.fromCOO(numRows, numCols, entries)
```

The matrix will be stored in CSC format on the machine. Printing the example input above will yield the following output:

```
1 x 8 CSCMatrix
(0,0) 6.128832321
(0,1) 7.738270234
(0,3) 0.438472867
(0,5) 5.486978435
(0,7) 5.295923198
```